# Tensorflow-gpu(1.7) Conda Installation - Cannot create session

Tags: session, tensorflow, cuda, keras

The command

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```

is now installing Tensorflow-gpu 1.7 by default, which is always throwing an error of "Cannot create session"

Here is the traceback in a screenshot :

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.Session()
```

> 2018-04-26 16:34:37.971115: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
>   2018-04-26 16:34:38.588037: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1344] Found device 0 with properties: 
>   name: Tesla M40 24GB major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.112
>   pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0
>   totalMemory: 22.40GiB freeMemory: 10.62GiB
>   2018-04-26 16:34:38.588119: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1423] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
>   2018-04-26 16:34:38.604343: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:167] Internal: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/home/16mcmi17/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1509, in **init**
>       super(Session, self).**init**(target, graph, config=config)
>     File "/home/16mcmi17/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 638, in **init**
>       self._session = tf_session.TF_NewDeprecatedSession(opts, status)
>     File "/home/16mcmi17/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 516, in **exit**
>       c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.

Earlier tensorflow-gpu 1.4 was working fine.

I want to know whether the problem is with the version or something else?
Also, How can I install tensorflow-gpu with conda (not pip) with a specific version?

Answer (score 2):

According to this part of your trace:

> Internal: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is
>   insufficient for CUDA runtime version

It seems like you are not meeting the CUDA version requirement. Tensorflow 1.4 required CUDA 8.0+, while Tensorflow 1.7 needs CUDA 9.0+.

Try upgrading your CUDA to 9.0 ([CUDA installation guide for Linux](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here is my installed packages, it is having cuda-toolkit 9.0

Comment: It is a bit hard to give you another answer without more information about your system and libraries. If you had another version of CUDA previously installed, it is possible your environment paths + simlink still point to that one and not the new one.